# Swiper как сделать что бы при клике на карточку переходила по ссылке без отработки события клик?

Tags: javascript, swiper

Swiper как сделать что бы при клике на карточку переходила по ссылке без отработки события клик, но при этом сохранилось пролистывание слайдов при наведении мыши

```
<a href="" class="block__side">
                        <div class="image-slider swiper-container">
                            <!-- Слайдер -->
                            <div class="image-slider__wrapper swiper-wrapper">
                                <div class="image-slider__slide swiper-slide">
                                    <div class="image-slider__image">
                                        <img src="img/01.jpg" alt="Картинка">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                
                            </div>
                            
                            <!-- Добавляем, если нам нужна пагинация -->
                            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="block__content">
                            <p class="block__name">Название товара</p>
                            <p class="block__price">10 000 руб</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
```

```
let myImageSlider = new Swiper('.image-slider', {

        simulateTouch: true,
        touchRatio: 1,
        touchAngle: 45,
        grabCursor: true,
        
        autoHeight: false,
        slidesPerView: 1,
        watchOverflow: true,
        spaceBetween: 0,
        slidesPerGroup: 1,
        centeredSlides: false,
        initialSlide: 0,
        speed: 500,
        noSwipingClass: 'swiper-no-swiping',
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            type: 'bullets',
            clickable:true,
            
        },
        effect: 'fade',
        fadeEffect: {
            crossFade: true,
        },
    });
    let thumbs = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-pagination-bullet');
    thumbs.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).trigger('click');
    }));
```

Comment: Картинку ссылкой обернуть <a><img></a>